# Run-time error 1004 when copy variable data value to end of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate the values for cells in a given row (say C3:F3) and in that same row (on the same worksheet) go to first empty cell to the left of the cells that were concatenated (say B3) and input the concatenated values. The code below works the first time but I keep on getting a run-time error 1004 when the following line of code is run `ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = varConctnt`, that is, the next set of cells in the next row are selected (say C4:F4) and I want to input the concatenated value in cell B4. I've done my best to declare objects to get around the issue but the error keeps on appearing.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ConcatenateReal2()

Dim rng As Range, iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, i As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Range("C3").Select

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.End(xlToRight), ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

Dim varConctnt As Variant

    For iRow = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    For iCol = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

        If Not rng(iRow, iCol).Value = vbNullString Then

        varConctnt = varConctnt & "," & rng(iRow, iCol).Value

    End If

    Next iCol

    Range("B3").Activate

    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

        ActiveCell.Value = varConctnt

    Else

        ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = varConctnt

    End If

    varConctnt = ""

skip1:

    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: check the value of `varConctnt` it could be empty

Comment: If there's no content below B3 then End(xlDown) will go to the bottom of the sheet, and you can't offset 1 row from there.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Much appreciated! I've selected cell B2 and it works perfectly. I'll try your code below and let you know how it runs. It probably more efficient than mine. Also do you have any recommendations for VBA learning resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Untested)

```
Sub ConcatenateReal2()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim sep, rw as Range, v, s

    With ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
        Set rng = .Parent.Range(.End(xlToRight), .End(xlDown))
    End With

    For Each rw in rng.Rows     'loop over rows
        sep = "" 'reset separator 
        s = ""
        For Each c in rw.Cells
            v = c.value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                s = s & sep & v
                sep = ","    
            end if
        next c
        rw.cells(1).offset(0, -1).value = s 
    Next rw     

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, your code is far more efficient and less complicated! Any tips/resources on learning VBA would be much appreciated.